# How to override @XmlRootElement with custom name?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-restcontroller

When I try use a 'javax.xml.bind.annotation' based class from a `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController`, I **don't** see the value in the `name` attribute showing up in the response. I am using both `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody` and `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody` in my RestController.

E.g., a class `Foo` has an annotation of `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="foo")`.

What I get back is `<Foo>` and not `<foo>`. The latter is what I am trying to achieve.

Can someone please help me ?

TIA.

Comment: Which message converter are you using for XML content-type? Please provide your spring mvc configuration

Comment: `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` is what I think I should use. I don't have any message converters configured at the moment. Is there a particular `SerializationFeature` I should use for this message converter within my SpringBoot 1.4.1 RestController application ? I have `jackson-dataformat-xml` as a pom dependency in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had no luck yet, try using Jackson XML annotations instead of JAXB's ones:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="foo")
public class Foo{
...
}
```

You should have this annotation available as it is packaged on `jackson-dataformat-xml` dependency which you stated already had included in your project.

If you prefer to use JAXB annotations, you should configure `spring-mvc` to use `org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` as XML message converter instead of Jackson's one.